# PHP SQLite help needed inputting from post data

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I have the following code:

```
try
   {

       $DBH = new PDO('sqlite:dataDb_PDO.sqlite');

       $stmt = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO table(Firstname,Lastname,Datetime) VALUES(:field1,:field2,Datetime('now')");
       $stmt->execute(array(':field1' => $_POST['Pfirstname'], ':field2' => $_POST['Plastname']));


       $db = NULL;


   }
   catch(PDOException $e)
   {
       print 'Exception : '.$e->getMessage();
   }
```

But, not matter what I seem to do, I get errors

2015/05/18 08:45:51 [error] 14466#0: *907 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in /var/http/submit.php on line 44" while reading response header from upstream, client: xx, server: , request: "POST /submit.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "192.168.44.129", referrer: "http://xx/"

I've been trying to follow various examples online for a few days and getting no where. Please help!?

Answer (score 1):

Your sql query is wrong and it is failing, you cannot use datetime function inside the query, if you want to insert current date and time use following query:

```
 $stmt = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO table(Firstname,Lastname,Datetime) VALUES(:field1,:field2, date('now')");
```

Comment: Why? And `now()` does not seem to be a valid sqlite function: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: My Bad, I have edited answer, it should be  date('now')

Comment: My question remains, why not `datetime()`? It seems that is what the column type is, judging by the name :-)

Comment: Hmm... Datetime('now') was working before I used the fields/array to put the data in - now it isn't and causing issues. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

`table` is a [reserved word](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) in sqlite, so you would need to quote it:

```
$stmt = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO `table`(Firstname,Lastname,Datetime) VALUES(:field1,:field2,Datetime('now')");
```

Apart from that you should probably set up PDO to throw exceptions so that it will tell you directly what goes wrong:

```
$DBH = new PDO('sqlite:dataDb_PDO.sqlite');
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: Thank you, that error handling is good - I made some silly mistakes including leaving out the end bracket in the values part... Also, Datetime('now') isn't working since changing to using the array/field part (this used to work with static data before). Any idea why?